# How to get MIN from another sheet and ignore #VALUE or if is not number?

Tags: excel

I try to get value from column **S** but i have `#VALUE!` is them, i want to ignore that value and get me min value.

i try this:

```
=MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(comenzi!S4:S5),comenzi!S4:S5))
```

If i put:

```
=MIN(comenzi!S4:S5)
```

get me a value, but i want to **S4** to **S1000**, and i have that `#VALUE!`

I put some picture:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=MIN(IF(ISERROR(comenzi!S4:S5),"",comenzi!S4:S5))
```

**Note**: Commit this formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+.<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Infact, your formula `=MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(comenzi!S4:S5),comenzi!S4:S5))` should also work when entered by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+.<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

See images below:

[image]

and `comenzi` sheet is

[image]

Comment: Ok work for S4:S5, but if i put a a bigger range, S4:S120 where i have #VALUE! doesn't work

Comment: @Vladut - Forgot to mention, commit the formula by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: @Vladut - Oops! there was an issue with my formula, I've changed it now kindly check.

Comment: Nop, same result, and i pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter i put  a picture in question

Comment: If i put =MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(comenzi!S4:S5),comenzi!S4:S5)) , get me 0 value

Comment: @Vladut - Only reason that I currently see its not working is committing formula by entering Ctrl+Shift+Enter. See images in my answer its working fine.

Comment: @Vladut - Even your formula is working for me when committed by Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: I understand, but when i press CTRL+Shift+Enter nothing happens, hmm :-?

Comment: @Vladut - Or else if you can share your file with me,I can look into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112489/discussion-between-vladut-and-mrig).